# How to pass new data in to UILabel instead of adding data to the already created string?

Tags: ios, swift

Every time I hit generate the password gets bigger, how do I just change the string every time the button is pressed?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let lettersAndNumbers = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "1", "2", "3"]
    
    var password: String = ""
    
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordText: UILabel!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    @IBAction func generateButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        for _ in 1...6 {
            password += lettersAndNumbers.randomElement()!
            passwordText.text = password
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add `self.password = ""` before `for _ in 1...6 {`

Comment: You're keeping a reference to the password variable, so the first time you hit generate, it adds the 6 characters, and those are stored in the password variable. Then the next time you hit generate, it takes the already 6 characters, and adds 6 more. So you want to reset the password variable just before you start the generate loop. password = ""; for int n... etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simply appending 6 new characters every time `generateButton` is called.

You need to reset `password` instead before appending the characters.

```
@IBAction func generateButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    password = ""
    for _ in 1...6 {
        password += lettersAndNumbers.randomElement()!
    }
    passwordText.text = password
}
```

Unrelated to your question, but you don't need to update the text field in each iteration of the loop, you only need to do it once after `password` was updated.

You can also get rid of the loop completely by using `compactMap` and then `joined` to update `password` in a single line, so you don't need to reset it, you can just assign the new value directly.

```
@IBAction func generateButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    password = (1...6).compactMap { _ in lettersAndNumbers.randomElement() }.joined()
    passwordText.text = password
}
```

Comment: I'm very new to programming, your first way worked perfectly. The 2nd one im yet to learn.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your **generateButton** code to this one.

```
@IBAction func generateButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        for _ in 1...6 {
            password += lettersAndNumbers.randomElement()!
        }
            passwordText.text = password
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `didSet` to change the text of the label whenever the password changes. didSet is called immediately `after the new value is saved`.

```swift
var password: String = "" {
  didSet {
    passwordText.text = password
  }
} 
@IBAction func generateButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        for _ in 1...6 {
            password += lettersAndNumbers.randomElement()!
        }
    }
```